# Reset the Launchpad to fix the ordering in macOS Catalina

Tags: macos, applications, mojave, catalina, launchpad

When I was using Yosemite in my old mac, I can simply use `defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock` to fix the ordering of apps but it is not working in macOS Catalina 10.15

Now I have only the pre-installed apps like App Store, Notes, Music etc. in my launchpad.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in MacOS Catalina 10.15.2

```
defaults write com.apple.dock ResetLaunchPad -bool true; killall Dock
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [Launchpad Manager](http://launchpadmanager.com). It’s the only tool that I’m aware of that will allow you to edit/control the Launchpad.